# Autohiding flash notices in Ruby on Rails app (and disable pushing down)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am building my first Rails app for phsyiotherapists to manage their patients and exercises.

When I do actions in my app it shows a notice in the top of my screen.

[image]

How can I autohide this notice after a couple of seconds?

How can I prevent the notice from 'pushing down' the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I autohide this notice after a couple of seconds?

You'll be best **using JQuery to hide the flash element** when it loads

This is some of our live code:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/admin/application.js.coffee
flashCallback = ->
    $(".flash").animate
      height: 0
      opacity: 0
    , 350
    , ->
      $(this).remove()

$ ->
    $(".flash").bind 'click', (ev) =>
        flashCallback()
    setTimeout flashCallback, 3000
```

This basically sets the "flash" element to disappear (fade out) after 3s (3000ms)

---

> How can I prevent the notice from 'pushing down' the content?

You'll be best using the [`position: absolute` or `position: fixed`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) **CSS styling** for your `flash` element:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
.flash {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%; 
    right: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RickPeck! This solution worked to autohide the notices. I chose .slideUp() instead of .animate for my application.